# 64 bit visual studio not available on website spark

Tags: 64-bit, visual-studio-2012, msdn, websitespark

I have a website spark account that I find very beneficial.

I run a 64 bit PC and looking to download visual studio 2012 from website spark - but the 32bit (X86) is only available. Any idea why 64 bit isn't available or when it might be available?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no 64bit version of Visual Studio because it uses a combination of 32bit *and* 64bit DLLs as it needs in respect to programs you are developing (and debugging). You can install it on both 32bit and 64bit systems and will work.

Comment: VS uses remote debugging [see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184681.aspx) to allow 32-bit Visual Studio to debug 64bit DLLs.  64-bit Visual Studio could have used a similar strategy to debug 32bit DLLs.  A better explanation posted is [posted by Rico Mariani](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

There is no 64bit version of Visual Studio.

Not on spark sites, not anywhere.

The Visual Studio team has decided not to produce one, as the overheads and complication of having a 64bit version outweighed the benefits.

The 32bit version will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no 64-bit version of Visual Studio.

The 32-bit version will work fine on 64-bit systems.